# Best way to go back 10 pages with selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to crawl several profiles.

My current code is:

```
all_users = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,

    for pages in range(2,14):
                for user in all_users:
                    profile_links = user.get_attribute('href')
                    names_searched.append(profile_links)
                go_profile(names_searched, counter, driver)
                driver.back()
                scroll(driver)
                nxt_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class, \'artdeco-pagination__button--next\')]").click()))
                counter += 1
```

I'm not 100% sure that the next page button works properly for now. So far it has not been able to find the next button. If I can get help with finding the next button from linkedin search results that would be helpful.

My biggest issue is I need to go back 10 pages to the original url to the search result page where it started off.

For example, if I was on page 2 of the search result, I want to go through all the profiles available on that page then go back to page 2 then click next button to go to page 3. On page 3 I want to crawl all profiles, go back to page 3 than click next button for 4 and so on.

Each page has about 10 profiles so that is why I want to go back 10 pages.

Is there a better way to go back 10 pages than just doing  driver.back() 10 times?

Comment: Another way to approach this is running webdriver in memory, so there isn't an actual presence of the browser.  You might find that the forward and back function cleaner this way in less time during testing.  The drawback is you can't see anything in memory unless you have a lot of logging!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way around, instead of clicking multiple times to go back to a number of pages back, you can directly do it by using the URL.

```
if you are on the first page of people's search 
https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?keywords=your_query

if you are on the 2nd page of people's search 
https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?keywords=your_query&page=2

if you are on the 10th page of people's search 
https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?keywords=your_query&page=10
```

As you might notice, the URL contains information about the page you are on. And let's say you're on page 10 and want to return back to the 1st page, simply use the URL of page 1 to return back to it directly.

I hope it's useful.